# client applications connection to kubernetes serviced pods are timing out if no container is listening

Tags: kubernetes

i'm facing my own program stuck in connecting to a serviced pod in my kubernetes cluster.
Let me explain, let's take a curl program trying to connect one of the containers in a serviced pod from outside the cluster.

```
curl -X GET http://192.168.1.105:31003/ready
{ "ready": true }
```

no error, the service is doing good :)

When my deployment is deleted, the curl command reports the network error as expected

```
curl -v -X GET http://192.168.1.105:31003/ready
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.1.105:31003; Connection refused
```

Now, if i replace the webserver container in pod by a sleep 3600 container, start the deployment, then the curl command is timing out

```
curl -v -X GET http://192.168.1.105:31003/ready
* About to connect() to 192.168.1.105 port 31003 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.1.105...
* Connection timed out
* Failed connect to 192.168.1.105:31003; Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.1.105:31003; Connection timed out
```

I don't understand why the curl client doesn't get an error when it tries to connect to a container running sleep with no port opened!
My pod has no liveness or readiness probe set, so all containers are declared as 'running'.

```
kubectl get pod
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
alis-green-core-2hlgx           3/3     Running   0          104s

kubectl get service
NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                           AGE
service-alis-green-core         NodePort    172.30.28.252   <none>        11003:31003/TCP,11903:31229/TCP,11904:32364/TCP,11007:31183/TCP,14281:31419/TCP   2m11s

kubectl get endpoints
NAME                            ENDPOINTS                                                           AGE
service-alis-green-core         10.129.0.44:14281,10.129.0.44:11903,10.129.0.44:11007 + 2 more...   2m52s
```

I guess the issue is related to some kube-proxy configuration i may have missed.
Thanks

Comment: In the case where there are no Pods behind the Service, it knows there is nothing to actually connect to and so it can shut down its network listener.  On the one hand, I'm slightly surprised you're getting "connection time out" and not, say, "connection reset by peer"; but on the other, as far as the Service knows, it has Pods behind it and they're passing all of their probes.  Do you have a reason to intentionally configure the system this way?

Comment: i tryed to reduce the complexity of my issue to the maximum possible, to eliminate bad questions. In fact, i have set liveness and readiness probes to my containers, and i can observe that as long as the pod has not all containers ready, the request is not forwarded (expected), but in my case, as soon as the pod is started up, my guess is that the kube-proxy accepts the connection but doesn't forward it to the container.